# Trying to set initial state of UISwitch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a `UISwitch` that is contained inside a Prototype cell which is a subclass of a `UITableViewCell`.  This prototype cell contains a `UISwitch` whose initial state I wish to set to false when the app initially starts, and whose state I wish to store whenever the user changes it.  My problem is trying to get a reference to the `UISwitch` from within the `UITableViewController`, when the `UISwitch` is contained inside the prototype cell.

Here is my relevant code:

Inside my `AppDelegate` I have the following:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        if !NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isNotFirstLaunch") {
           //Set switchState to false and isNotFirstLaunch to true
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "switchState")
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isNotFirstLaunch")

           //Sync NSUserDefaults
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
```

Inside my `UITableViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  //this line below is commented out because I don't have a reference to the UISwitch in question, but I imagine it would be something along these lines:
  //switchState.on =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchState")
}
//This block of code I was able to connect to the UISwitch directly in the storyboard file, so I know this works.
@IBAction func stateChanged(withSwitchState switchState: UISwitch) {
        if switchState.on {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(switchState.on, forKey: "switchState")
        } else {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(switchState.on, forKey: "switchState")
        }
    }
```

And inside my class for the prototype cell:

```
class SwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var switchControl: UISwitch!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.switchControl.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    }

}
```

I need a reference to the `UISwitch` that is contained inside my prototype cell, WITHIN my `UITableViewController` class, such that it's initial state is set to false as established in my `AppDelegate` class, and it's state is maintained going forward whenever the user changes the state of the `UISwitch`.

Comment: set the state in inside the cellforrow method

Comment: How do I get a reference to the custom cell class inside "cellForRowAtIndexPath"?  When I do this:  

if cell is SwitchTableViewCell {
            ...
        }

I'm unable to use "cell" to get a reference to the UISwitch parameter inside it's class.

Comment: @syedfa check my answer to get a reffernce to your cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SwitchTableViewCell

    if !NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("switchState")
   {
      cell. switchControl.setOn(true, animated: true)

    }
    else
     {
        cell. switchControl.setOn(false, animated: true)
     }
     cell. switchControl.tag = indexPath.row
     cell. switchControl.addTarget(self, action: "switchChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


    return cell

}



func switchChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
if switchState.on {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "switchState")
        } else {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "switchState")
        }
      self.tableview.reloadData()
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your storyboard, set a tag for the `UISwitch`, e.g. `1`. Then, in `viewDidLoad`, get the cell using `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(someIndexPath)`:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(<insert your cell's index path here>)
```

Then, get the `UISwitch`:

```
let mySwitch = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UISwitch
mySwitch.on = ...
```

Alternative approaches:

- Cast the cell you got from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to `SwitchTableViewCell`, and access the `switchControl` directly
- If your whole view controller is a form, you can use [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) to simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this methpd in your custom cell class.

```
    class func cellForTableView(tableView: UITableView, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> SwitchTableViewCell {
    let kSwitchTableViewCellIdentifier = "kSwitchTableViewCellIdentifier"
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SwitchTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: kSwitchTableViewCellIdentifier)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kSwitchTableViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell

    return cell
}
```

and in your tableViewController's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method access the cell as below

```
let cell = SwitchTableViewCell.cellForTableView(tableView, atIndexPath: indexPath)
```

now you can simply access your swicth like this

```
cell.switchControl.... // do something
```